# Comparing two hashmaps for equal values and same key sets?

Tags: java, collections, hashmap, comparison

How can I best compare two `HashMap`s, if I want to find out if none of them contains different keys than the other, and if the values of that keys match each other.

```
Map<objA, objB> mapA = new HashMap<objA, objB>();
mapA.put("A", "1");
mapA.put("B", "2");

Map<objA, objB> mapB = new HashMap<objA, objB>();
mapB.put("D", "4");
mapB.put("A", "1");
```

When comparing A with B, it should fail due to different keys B and D.

How could I best compare non-sorted hashmaps?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Make an `equals` check on the `keySet()` of both `HashMap`s.

***NOTE:***

If your `Map` contains `String` keys then it is no problem, but if your Map contains `objA` type keys then you need to make sure that your class `objA` implements `equals()`.

Comment: Yes but the OP also wants that they have the same mapping. And note that you need to override hashCode as well.

Comment: Don't you forget to override `hashCode()` if you override `.equals()` as the guy said

Answer (score 76):

Simply use :

`mapA.equals(mapB);`

> Compares the specified object with this map for equality. Returns true
>   if the given object is also a map and the two maps represent the **same**
>   mappings

Comment: Is this for Java or Android? On Android, the description for `equals` is [different](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29431623/145173).

Comment: @EdwardBrey The description you state does the same thing. And I don't know where you got this definition because it's the same on the Android doc: http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Map.html#equals(java.lang.Object)

Comment: The documentation for the interface method [Map.equals](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Map.html#equals(java.lang.Object)) is as you quoted. However, `HashMap` implements the `equals` method of that interface via [AbstractMap.equals](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/AbstractMap.html#equals(java.lang.Object)), which has the weaker guarantee that I quoted. The `AbstractMap` code matches its documentation. It seems to me that `HashMap` violates the contract of the interface.

Comment: @EdwardBrey Then tell me the difference between what you quoted? Because I don't see any. It does the same thing... _"This implementation first checks the structure of object. If it is not a map or of a **different size**, this returns false. Otherwise it iterates its **own entry set**, looking up each **entry's key** in **object**. If any **value** does not equal **the other map's value** for the **same** key, this returns false. Otherwise it returns true."_

Comment: I was concerned that it doesn't say that it iterates over the other entry set and does a lookup the other way. However, since, as you highlighted, it checks for identical size and since keys must be unique in each map, it doesn't need to. A comparison starting from just one side is sufficient.

Answer (score 11):

Compare every key in mapB against the counterpart in mapA. Then check if there is any key in mapA not existing in mapB

```
public boolean mapsAreEqual(Map<String, String> mapA, Map<String, String> mapB) {

    try{
        for (String k : mapB.keySet())
        {
            if (!mapA.get(k).equals(mapB.get(k))) {
                return false;
            }
        } 
        for (String y : mapA.keySet())
        {
            if (!mapB.containsKey(y)) {
                return false;
            }
        } 
    } catch (NullPointerException np) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work if you have null values in your map. Given the following two maps, it will fail the comparison:

    final Map<String, Double> map1 = new HashMap<>();
  map1.put("key1", new Double(0.0));
  map1.put("key2", new Double(75.0));
  map1.put("key3", null);
  final Map<String, Double> map2 = new HashMap<>();
  map2.put("key1", Double.valueOf("0.0"));
  map2.put("key2", 75.0);
  map2.put("key3", null);

Answer (score 3):

```
/* JAVA 8 using streams*/
   public static void main(String args[])
    {
        Map<Integer, Boolean> map = new HashMap<Integer, Boolean>();
        map.put(100, true);
        map.put(1011, false);
        map.put(1022, false);

        Map<Integer, Boolean> map1 = new HashMap<Integer, Boolean>();
        map1.put(100, false);
        map1.put(101, false);
        map1.put(102, false);

        boolean b = map.entrySet().stream().filter(value -> map1.entrySet().stream().anyMatch(value1 -> (value1.getKey() == value.getKey() && value1.getValue() == value.getValue()))).findAny().isPresent();
        System.out.println(b);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public boolean compareMap(Map<String, String> map1, Map<String, String> map2) {

    if (map1 == null || map2 == null)
        return false;

    for (String ch1 : map1.keySet()) {
        if (!map1.get(ch1).equalsIgnoreCase(map2.get(ch1)))
            return false;

    }
    for (String ch2 : map2.keySet()) {
        if (!map2.get(ch2).equalsIgnoreCase(map1.get(ch2)))
            return false;

    }

    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you have two maps lets say map1 and map2 then using java8 Streams,we can compare maps using code below.But it is recommended to use equals rather then != or ==

```
boolean b = map1.entrySet().stream().filter(value -> 
            map2.entrySet().stream().anyMatch(value1 -> 
            (value1.getKey().equals(value.getKey()) && 
  value1.getValue().equals(value.getValue())))).findAny().isPresent();   


System.out.println("comparison  "+b);
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple and good algorithm for such a comparison could be:

```
    Map<Integer, Boolean> map1 = new HashMap<Integer, Boolean>();
    map1.put(100, false);
    map1.put(101, false);
    map1.put(102, false);

    Map<Integer, Boolean> map2 = new HashMap<Integer, Boolean>();
    map2.put(100, false);
    map2.put(1011, false);
    map2.put(1022, false);

    if (!map1.keySet().equals(map2.keySet())) {
        result = false;
    } else {
        result = map1.keySet()
                .stream()
                .allMatch(key -> map1.get(key).equals(map2.get(key)));
    }
```

Simply you'll have to compare the set of keys, if they are equal, then compare the values for each key on both maps.