# How to compare Two hash maps

Tags: java, collections, hashmap

let's take an example :

```
Syntax :        
    Map<String,Map<String,String>> A = new HashMap<>();
    Map<String,Map<String,String>> B = new HashMap<>();
Implementation :
    Map<TableA,Map<AID,AVAL>> A = new HashMap<>();
    Map<TableB,Map<BID,BVAL>> B = new HashMap<>();
```

Compare HashMaps A & B based on the keys `TableA` and `AID` & `TableB` and `BID`

What is optimized way to iterate these hashmaps?

Comment: Please refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20969211/comparing-two-hashmaps-for-equal-values-and-same-key-sets!

Comment: Please explain why you need something besides `a.equals(b)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should define a bit better what you mean with comparing the maps. You want to compare keys and values? You could make a copy of the second map, cycle on the first and remove the keys of the first from the copy of the second. The keys that are left from copy of the second are those in the second and not in the first. On the other hand, those in the first and not in the second, you won't find them in the cycle.

Comment: Actually i have map with in the map if you see the above logic. can you please show me the logic

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand.

Answer (score 1):

The two Maps do not necessarily have the same number of elements and a given map
can have no elements. When we compare the two Maps, if the two Maps are equal then
it is fine. If the two are unequal I want to identify (print) the elements that are in one Map but not the other map.

```
Map<String,String> map1 = new HashMap<String,String>();
        map1.put("A", "B");
        map1.put("C","D");
        map1.put("E","F");
        map1.put("E","G");


        Map<String,String> map2 = new HashMap<String,String>();
        map2.put("A", "B");
        map2.put("C","D");
        map2.put("E","F");
        map2.put("F","F");
        map2.put("G","G");

        if (map1.entrySet().containsAll(map2.entrySet())) {
              System.out.println("Map2 is a subset of Map1");
        }
        else {  // find map pairs that are in set 1 but not in set 2
                // expected result is key = E and value = G
        }

        if (map2.entrySet().containsAll(map1.entrySet())) {
              System.out.println("Map1 is a subset of Map2");
        }
        else {  // find map pairs that are in set 2 but not in set 1
               // expected result is key=F, value=F and key=G, value=G
        }

       //compare each entry of map
       for (final String key : map2.keySet()) {
           if (map1.containsKey(key)) {
                     System.out.println("Value:" + map1.get(key));
           }
       }
```

Answer (score 1):

I tried it, you have to go through keySet for TableA and TableB comparing

---

```
Iterator<Map.Entry<TableA ,Map<AID,AVAL>> itr1 = A.entrySet().iterator();
Iterator<Map.Entry<TableB ,Map<BID,BVAL>> itr2 = A.entrySet().iterator();
while(itr1.hasNext() && itr2.hasNext())
{
    Map.Entry<TableA ,Map<AID,AVAL>> entry1 = itr1.next();
    Map.Entry<TableB ,Map<BID,BVAL>> entry2 = itr2.next();
    if((entry1.getKey().equals(entry2.getKey())) 
    Sop("match");
    else Sop("Not FOund");
}
```

Comment: This depends on the order of the entry sets!!